# Getting error PHP Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController'

Tags: php, zend-framework

When I am trying to run zend code via command prompt, I am getting below mention error.

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController' not found in C:....

Currently my php version is 5.6.*
and composer.json php 5.3.3,
comoser.lock php 5.3.3,
composer version: 2.1.9

{

```
 namespace Bpl\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\Http\Client as HttpClient;
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;
use Zend\Json\Json;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
use Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp as SmtpTransport;
use Zend\Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions;
use RuntimeException;
use Enroll\Plugins\enrollPlugin;
use Zend\Soap\Client;
echo 'Hello namespace'; //exit();

/**
 * Bpl controller 
 * 
 * @method enrollPlugin enrollPlugin()
 */
class MyController extends AbstractActionController
{ 
    //echo 'Hello MyController'; exit();
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'Hello index'; exit();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How does your controller code look like? Without code it 's just guessing.

Comment: Yes share you code

Comment: Wait.. Why your "composer PHP" is different from your "PHP version"? I think you are mixing up things..

Comment: However, could you please also add the content of `composer.json` ? Are you sure you included all required libraries? Did you run `composer install` ?

Comment: Last but not least, action's name in zend controllers must always end with `action`, like `indexAction`. That `index` method will never be called from Zend's router..

Comment: My guess it that you're opening this file, not the front controller file in /public/index.php. Therefore vendor/autoload.php is not loaded and therefore the class is not found.